# WordPress plugin – Save extra image metadata without PHP?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add custom functionality to the Image Details modal, and found that the easiest and probably also only way is to extend the `window.wp.media.view.ImageDetails` Backbone view and do as much as possible in JavaScript.

I’ve worked extensively with Backbone before, and making the DOM changes and adding the event listeners etc. won’t be a problem. However, I’m not sure how to go about loading the relevant metadata, and from where, when opening the modal in the first place – and after I’m done, I’m not sure how to save everything.

I have a hunch – or maybe more of a a hope – that the form in the Image Details modal is somehow serialized and stored in the `_wp_attachment_metadata` or to a a similar meta key, although I haven’t been able to find corresponding pieces of data in the database and the frontend as of yet.

My extended user interface will be quite custom, but the values it produces can easily be added to hidden input fields in the DOM.

Am I onto something though? Can this be done without touching PHP, and without adding more tables to the database?

Comment: hello dear Hein, many thanks for your ideas and thoughts you share here- well i hav a similar approach ... cf
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679425/parse-and-process-html-in-php-fetching-wordpress-plugin-metadata-with-a-scraper
for a list of meta-data of popular wordpress-plugins (cf. https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/browse/popular/ and gathering the first 50 URLs - that are 50 plugins which are of interest! The challenge is: i want to fetch meta-data of all the existing plugins. What i subsequently want to filter out after the fetch is done - any idea here!?